# PostgreSQL B+ tree implementation

Tags: postgresql, b-tree

Where can i get the PostgreSQL B+ tree implementation?

Comment: I've heard that Posgres is open source. So maybe you could take a look at the source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source from

http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/

As for finding the B+ tree implementation that's an exercise left for you.